# Can't randomize rotation for multiple objects along local axis

Tags: transforms

I'm trying to repeat Tip #72 (Randomize Transform) from [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/JMBMHSca_j0?t=3927)

And I can't figure out how to randomize rotation of multiple objects along **local** axis. In my case, objects are rotate along global axis despite I selected local orientation with pivot at individual origins.

[image: Using Randomize Transform]

However direct rotation by the hands works fine.
[image: Rotation by the hands]

Comment: it looks like it can only take the global axis into account

Comment: If you don't mind putting your screw /screws  in a collection, or linking them there, and using instances of them in the final product, which is probably a good idea anyway.. then Geometry Nodes give a simple solution..?